# IRB fails to run ruby gem function while ruby is successful

Tags: c, ruby, malloc

I recently made the following ruby gem (called sse):

```
#include <ruby.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

/*
 * Module handle
*/

static VALUE sse_module;

/*
 * All exceptions for this module
*/

static VALUE sse_FileNotFoundError;
static VALUE sse_ForkFailureError;
static VALUE sse_PipeFailureError;
static VALUE sse_WriteFailureError;
static VALUE sse_ReadFailureError;
static VALUE sse_WaitpidFailureError;
static VALUE sse_TimeoutError;

/*
 * General utilities
*/

char **split(char *str, char *sep) {
    char *arg = strtok(str, sep);
    size_t arg_list_size = 1;
    char **arg_list = malloc(sizeof(char*));

    arg_list[0] = malloc(strlen(arg));
    strncpy(arg_list[0], arg, strlen(arg));

    while((arg = strtok(NULL, sep)) != NULL) {
        arg_list = realloc(arg_list, (sizeof(char*))*(arg_list_size+1));
        arg_list[arg_list_size] = malloc(strlen(arg));
        strncpy(arg_list[arg_list_size], arg, strlen(arg));
        ++arg_list_size;
    }

    arg_list = realloc(arg_list, (sizeof(char*))*(arg_list_size));
    arg_list[arg_list_size] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    arg_list[arg_list_size] = (char*)NULL;

    return arg_list;
}

/*
 * Ruby classes and functions
*/

VALUE rb_execute_sh(VALUE self, VALUE rb_stdin, VALUE rb_timeout, VALUE rb_command) {
    int stdin_ends[2];
    int stdout_ends[2];
    int stderr_ends[2];

    if(pipe(stdin_ends) == -1 || pipe(stdout_ends) == -1 || pipe(stderr_ends) == -1) {
        rb_raise(sse_PipeFailureError, "%s:%d (%d) pipe: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    char **command_list = split(StringValueCStr(rb_command), (char*)" ");
    char *stdin_buf = StringValueCStr(rb_stdin);
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid > 0) {
        size_t stdout_buf_size = 0;
        size_t stderr_buf_size = 0;
        size_t stdout_buf_max = 1;
        size_t stderr_buf_max = 1;
        char *stdout_buf = malloc(1);
        char *stderr_buf = malloc(1);

        stdout_buf[0] = '\0';
        stderr_buf[0] = '\0';

        time_t start = time(NULL);
        time_t timeout = NUM2INT(rb_timeout);
        int sent_stdin = 0;

        close(stdin_ends[0]);
        close(stdout_ends[1]);
        close(stderr_ends[1]);

        while(difftime(time(NULL), start) < timeout) {
            int status = waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG);

            if(status == -1) {
                rb_raise(sse_WaitpidFailureError, "%s:%d (%d) waitpid: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));
            } else if(status == 0) {
                fd_set write_set;
                fd_set read_set;
                struct timeval select_timeout = { 0, 0 };
                int maxfd = (stdin_ends[1] > stdout_ends[0] ? (stdin_ends[1] > stderr_ends[0] ? stdin_ends[1] : stderr_ends[0]) : (stdout_ends[0] > stderr_ends[0] ? stdout_ends[0] : stderr_ends[0]));

                FD_ZERO(&write_set);
                FD_ZERO(&read_set);

                if(sent_stdin == 0) {
                    FD_SET(stdin_ends[1], &write_set);
                }

                FD_SET(stdout_ends[0], &read_set);
                FD_SET(stderr_ends[0], &read_set);

                select(maxfd+1, &read_set, &write_set, NULL, &select_timeout);

                if(FD_ISSET(stdin_ends[1], &write_set)) {
                    sent_stdin = 1;

                    if(write(stdin_ends[1], stdin_buf, strlen(stdin_buf)) == -1) {
                        rb_raise(sse_WriteFailureError, "%s:%d (%d) write: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));
                    }

                    close(stdin_ends[1]);
                }

                if(FD_ISSET(stdout_ends[0], &read_set)) {
                    char tmp_buf[251];
                    ssize_t bytes_read = read(stdout_ends[0], tmp_buf, 250);

                    if(bytes_read == -1) {
                        rb_raise(sse_ReadFailureError, "%s:%d (%d) read: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));
                    }

                    tmp_buf[bytes_read] = '\0';

                    while((stdout_buf_size + bytes_read+1) >= stdout_buf_max) {
                        stdout_buf_max *= 2;
                        stdout_buf = realloc(stdout_buf, stdout_buf_max);
                    }

                    strncpy(stdout_buf, tmp_buf, bytes_read);
                    stdout_buf_size += bytes_read;
                    stdout_buf[stdout_buf_size] = '\0';
                }

                if(FD_ISSET(stderr_ends[0], &read_set)) {
                    char tmp_buf[251];
                    ssize_t bytes_read = read(stderr_ends[0], tmp_buf, 250);

                    if(bytes_read == -1) {
                        rb_raise(sse_ReadFailureError, "%s:%d (%d) read: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));
                    }

                    tmp_buf[bytes_read] = '\0';

                    while((stderr_buf_size + bytes_read+1) >= stderr_buf_max) {
                        stderr_buf_max *= 2;
                        stderr_buf = realloc(stderr_buf, stderr_buf_max);
                    }

                    strncpy(stderr_buf, tmp_buf, bytes_read);
                    stderr_buf_size += bytes_read;
                    stderr_buf[stderr_buf_size] = '\0';
                }
            } else {
                close(stdout_ends[0]);
                close(stderr_ends[1]);
                VALUE result = rb_ary_new2(3);
                rb_ary_store(result, 0, INT2NUM(difftime(time(NULL), start)));
                rb_ary_store(result, 1, rb_str_new_cstr(stdout_buf));
                rb_ary_store(result, 2, rb_str_new_cstr(stderr_buf));
                return result;
            }
        }

        kill(SIGINT, pid);
        rb_raise(sse_TimeoutError, "Proccess took too long to finish.\n");
    } else if(pid == 0) {
        dup2(stdin_ends[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(stdout_ends[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(stderr_ends[1], STDERR_FILENO);
        close(stdin_ends[1]);
        close(stdout_ends[0]);
        close(stderr_ends[0]);

        if(execvp(command_list[0], command_list) == -1) {
            rb_raise(sse_ForkFailureError, "%s:%d (%d) execvp: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));
        }
    } else {
        rb_raise(sse_FileNotFoundError, "%s:%d (%d) execvp: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    VALUE thunderfury_blessed_blade_of_the_windseeker = rb_ary_new2(3);
    rb_ary_store(thunderfury_blessed_blade_of_the_windseeker, 0, INT2NUM(42));
    rb_ary_store(thunderfury_blessed_blade_of_the_windseeker, 1, rb_str_new_cstr("this is stdout"));
    rb_ary_store(thunderfury_blessed_blade_of_the_windseeker, 2, rb_str_new_cstr("this is stderr"));
    return thunderfury_blessed_blade_of_the_windseeker;
}

/*
 * Initialize the module
*/

void Init_sse() {
    sse_module = rb_define_module("sse");

    sse_FileNotFoundError = rb_define_class_under(sse_module, "FileNotFoundError", rb_eStandardError);
    sse_ForkFailureError = rb_define_class_under(sse_module, "ForkFailureError", rb_eStandardError);
    sse_PipeFailureError = rb_define_class_under(sse_module, "PipeFailureError", rb_eStandardError);
    sse_WriteFailureError = rb_define_class_under(sse_module, "WriteFailureError", rb_eStandardError);
    sse_ReadFailureError = rb_define_class_under(sse_module, "ReadFailureError", rb_eStandardError);
    sse_WaitpidFailureError = rb_define_class_under(sse_module, "WaitpidFailureError", rb_eStandardError);
    sse_TimeoutError = rb_define_class_under(sse_module, "TimeoutError", rb_eStandardError);

    rb_define_global_function("execute_sh", rb_execute_sh, 3);
}
```

When running it from a script, it works great:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:sse-ruby nchambers$ cat client.rb
require './sse'
result = execute_sh('', 10, 'hostname')
puts "=>#{result[0]}<=\n=>#{result[1]}<=\n=>#{result[2]}<=\n"
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:sse-ruby nchambers$ ruby client.rb
=>0<=
=>admins-MacBook-Pro-2.local
<=
=><=
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:sse-ruby nchambers$
```

However, if I do the same thing from irb, I get this:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:sse-ruby nchambers$ irb
2.2.4 :001 > require './sse'
 => true
2.2.4 :002 > result = execute_sh('', 10, 'hostname')
 => [0, "\n.2.4 :003 > :in `execute_sh'\n\tfrom (irb):2\n\tfrom /Users/nchambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'\n", "irb(6804,0x7fffa88db3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff9ece81880: pointer being freed was not allocated\n*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug\n"]
2.2.4 :003 > puts "=>#{result[0]}<=\n=>#{result[1]}<=\n=>#{result[2]}<=\n"
=>0<=
=>
.2.4 :003 > :in `execute_sh'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/nchambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
<=
=>irb(6804,0x7fffa88db3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff9ece81880: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
<=
 => nil
2.2.4 :004 >
```

I can't see any reason why that would happen. So my question is, why does IRB fail where the script succeeds? Thank you!

Comment: What does your thing do?

Comment: At the moment, run rb_command (which must be an actual executable file) for roughly rb_timeout amount of seconds, at max. In my example, rb_timeout is set to 10, so `sleep 15` would raise a TimeoutError exception. `sleep 11` might get through, because precision timing isn't super important for this gem's purpose. Just as close to rb_timeout as possible.

Comment: In `split()`: what is the purpose of `arg_list[arg_list_size] = malloc(sizeof(char*)); arg_list[arg_list_size] = (char*)NULL;`? It seems to me that it only leaks memory.

Comment: The malloc is probably not necessary. The NULL assignment is, for execvp.

Comment: Why not use plain Ruby instead?

Comment: I don't see the relevance.

Comment: You’re writing a lot of overcomplicated C to accomplish something that Ruby can do just fine.

Comment: I still don't see the relevance. There are many languages that can do it fine, and this doesn't really seem that complicated to me. it forks, runs the command in the child, and in the parent loops for ~rb_timeout seconds while grabbing stderr, stdout from the command, and feeding it stdin.

Comment: It’s relevant because you’re writing a Ruby gem, so presumably you want to use it in Ruby. Ruby has built-in ways to spawn a process and get its output. If you don’t write a C extension, you’re also compatible with more Ruby implementations. Or are you writing it in C for fun?

Comment: its not relevant. I am doing this on a mac, so for that same logic I should do it in obj-c.

Comment: “for that same logic I should do it in obj-c”. No, I don’t think you understand the logic at all. You are writing a library for use *in Ruby*. You are writing *a lot of bad C* that you *don’t even need to write*. Write *good Ruby* instead so it’s portable and readable and actually works.

Comment: I do... I wrote a gem in C. You equate that to mean I should write the whole project in Ruby. I am well aware ruby has the capability to do this, but that is not important.

Comment: You still haven’t given an explanation for why it’s not important. Why can’t you write *this part* in Ruby?

Comment: Because I am doing it in C. If you don't want to answer my question, that is fine. I am not looking for a critique of the language choice, since its irrelevant to my question.

Comment: i kind of regret helping you do the wrong thing but I deleted my answer so feel free to delete your question now that it’s solved or w/e

Comment: As I said, you do not have to answer. Its definitely not the wrong thing, you just seem to not understand using the right tool for the job.

Comment: I already did answer. Didn’t you see it? Assumed you downvoted it so I deleted it, but it’s correct. Undeleted for a moment, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
arg_list[0] = malloc(strlen(arg));
strncpy(arg_list[0], arg, strlen(arg));
```

```
arg_list[arg_list_size] = malloc(strlen(arg));
strncpy(arg_list[arg_list_size], arg, strlen(arg));
```

no

```
arg_list[0] = malloc(strlen(arg) + 1);
strncpy(arg_list[0], arg, strlen(arg) + 1);
arg_list[0][strlen(arg)] = '\0';
```

```
arg_list[arg_list_size] = malloc(strlen(arg) + 1);
strncpy(arg_list[arg_list_size], arg, strlen(arg) + 1);
arg_list[arg_list_size][strlen(arg)] = '\0';
```

technically works

```
arg_list[0] = strdup(arg);
```

```
arg_list[arg_list_size] = strdup(arg);
```

it’s okay I guess

that’ll probably do what you think you want but is not a complete fix for the underlying problem, namely the C